# pound symbol in plain text email

Tags: asp.net, email

I am trying to insert a pound symbol into a plain text email using .net but it appears as Â£

Any ideas how I can fix this?

thanks

Comment: As a user, I have given up believing that the combined email systems of the world will ever *all* reliably transmit a £. In my own emails, I refer to sterling quantities with 'GBP' :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only way to get it working is to make sure you encode the email with the same character encoding as to what you decode it with. In this case, you are encoding the email in UTF-8 but [decoding it](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) as if it was Latin-1. It might be overkill for this case, but *[The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)* is a good read.

One solution is to add `Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8` as a header.

Comment: Of the [email](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email#Message_format). I don't know ASP.net, but [this](http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/101707-1.aspx) might help.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the declared character encoding of the email matches the character encoding you are actually using.

Answer (score 1):

Well, this depends on the character encoding you use for sending out your plaintext mails.

Remember, *there is no such thing as plaintext* - you always need to use an encoding, and there are many to choose from :-).

If you use an encoding that has a pound sign (Unicode encodings do, ASCII e.g. does not), then just output it normally, and it should work.

P.S. Also see this excellent article:

[The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)

Answer (score 0):

I realise it is two years since this thread was running, but clearly people still need an answer to this problem. My experience relates to 'plain text' e-mails, not HTML.

I have found that "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8" does not work correctly. The charset itself needs to be in quotes as:

"Content-Type: text/plain; charset='UTF-8'"

Of course several other charsets will work perfectly well too.

Answer (score -3):

Depends how you're inserting it, but a couple of options are...

```
&#36;
```

or

```
Convert.ToChar(35);
```

Comment: -1 `&#36;' is ASCII 36 aka "dollar sign", 35 would be hash sign.

Comment: The first won't work in a plain text email (which the question specified), the second only works if the character encoding is specified correctly.